# How is HTML attribute encoding/escaping different than regular HTML encoding?

Tags: html, security, escaping

I've noticed the OWASP recommends using [a different encoding method](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForHTMLAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) specifically for encoding HTML Attributes, and in ASP.NET MVC there is [a helper method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.attributeencode%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) specifically to encode attributes.

However, I haven't been able to think of any situation where an HTML-encoded string wouldn't work in the context of an HTML attribute. Are there cases where using standard HTML encoding would be insufficient or incorrect? If not, why are these extra methods provided in some frameworks?

(Note that [not all string escaping frameworks](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) provide such methods.)

Comment: Have you already looked at the [reference implementation of *Encoder*](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.java)?

Comment: @Gumbo: I hadn't, but I just did. It appears that the attribute encoder is exactly the same except that it doesn't consider spaces to be "immune" to encoding. Why would this be? If you didn't html-encode spaces in attributes, what undesirable effect might this have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a deeper look into the [reference implementation](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/), the `encodeForHTMLAttribute` method calls the `encode` method of the [*HTMLEntityCodec* class](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/HTMLEntityCodec.java) with a set of immune characters which do not need to be encoded. Inside the `encode` method, which is inherited from [*Codec* class](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/Codec.java), you can see that any non-alphanumeric character, which is not in the *immune* set, would be encoded by a character reference.

Now as you have already noticed that the *immune* sets for HTML and HTML attributes are different, especially in HTML attributes the space is not considered immune:

```
private final static char[]     IMMUNE_HTML = { ',', '.', '-', '_', ' ' };
private final static char[] IMMUNE_HTMLATTR = { ',', '.', '-', '_' };
```

The reason for that is probably because HTML attributes do not necessarily need to be quoted. An when the [quotes are missing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unquoted), a literal [space character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#space-character) would end the attribute value. In that case the space character needs to be encoded by a character reference to be interpreted as part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

One example off the top of my head is that if you have quoted text inside an attribute, you'll obviously have to escape quotes, while this isn't necessary for regular html encoding (though most frameworks do it anyway just to be extra safe).

In general, trying to escape html and css is incredibly complex. To make matters worse, browsers do not follow the standard exactly, even when there is one. Often times they'll be more lenient, allowing stuff like null characters instead of spaces in a script tag, which allows attackers to bypass naive escaping methods. And of course the exact behavior is different for every browser. The book **The Tangled Web** goes into detail on some of the more interesting pitfalls in this area.